# D3.js adjust rect to text size: getBBox()?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm creating a force directed graph using D3.js, see JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwxecn8q/.

The `text` and `rect` are placed in the same group. When appending the `rect`s I want to select the `text` element for the same group. Call `getBBox()` on it and use those values to resize the `rect` to fit the text "in" it. However, I'm unsure how to select the `text` element from the same group when appending the `rect`s...

Any suggestion on how to go about this?

The relevant code:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .distance(100)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);

force.nodes(graphData.nodes)
    .links(graphData.links)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graphData.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(graphData.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")




node.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.group);
})
    .call(force.drag);



node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name
})




force.on("tick", function () {
    link.attr("x1", function (d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the Bounding Box of the node (`g` element, which contains the text).

```
node.selectAll('rect')
    .attr("width", function(d) {return this.parentNode.getBBox().width;})
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pwxecn8q/3/

Comment: [This appears](http://jsfiddle.net/pwxecn8q/3/) to be the working fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @RB., I don't know what happened. I just updated the answer with the correct link.

Comment: No no, thank you! I've been banging my head against a brick wall, and you saved me!

Comment: Thanks man, it saved the time. That's the best solution I found.