# Adding background color to axis labels in D3 parallel coordinates

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm working on a modified version of [this D3 code](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3150059) for parallel coordinates. I would like to add a background color for the axis labels. I realize I cannot set a background color using CSS styles because this is SVG text, so I tried to append rectangles but to no avail. Here is what I wrote but it's not drawing anything:

```
           d3.selectAll(".label")  
                      .append("rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d){ return d3.select(this).node().getBBox().x - 5;})
                        .attr("y", function(d){ return d3.select(this).node().getBBox().y - 5;})
                        .attr("width", function(d){ return d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width;})
                        .attr("height", function(d) {return d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height;})
                        .style("stroke", "black")
                        .style("fill", "yellow");
```

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: 
based on comments, I appended to the parent g rather than the text label itself. Now the code looks like this:

```
  // Add an axis and title.
                 var gsvg= g.append("svg:g")
                      .attr("class", "axis")
                      .attr("id", "gsvg")
                      .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(yscale[d])); })
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

                    d3.selectAll("#gsvg")  
                      .append("rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d){ return this.parentNode.getBBox().x - 5;})
                        .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i%2 === 0 ? this.parentNode.getBBox().y - 20: this.parentNode.getBBox().y - 35;})
                        .attr("width", function(d){ return this.parentNode.getBBox().width;})
                        .attr("height", function(d) {return 20;})
                        .style("stroke", "lightgrey")
                        .style("stroke-width", 2)
                        .style("fill", function(d){
                            return self.fcolorMap[d];
                        })
                        .style("opacity", 0.5);

                    gsvg.append("svg:text")
                      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                      .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i%2 == 0 ? -14 : -30 } )
                      .attr("x",0)
                      .attr("class", "axis-label")
                      .text(function(d) { 
                        var s = d.split("|");
                        return s[s.length-1]; });
```

The only problem is now I need to figure out how to get the bounding boxes of the labels rather than those of the axes.

Comment: Is your selection a set of text elements? Because you cannot append a rect to a text element.

Comment: Answers like this one might help with a suitable approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075638/d3-js-adjust-rect-to-text-size-getbbox

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. I tried appending to the parent g and now the rectangles are drawn. The only problem is that I can't seem to get the bounding box of the label rather than that of the axis. A screenshot is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gn1lhedlr1wlu7g/Capture.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: I edited my question to add updated code based on your recommendation.

Comment: It works now. I just swapped the order to append the text before the rectangles and somehow this made parentNode.getBBox() return the correct values. Thanks for your help. Feel free to add your comments as an answer.

Comment: Can you please post your answer, so it will help me as well